# Specific regex positive look(around|ahead|behind) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking to match `/(?=\W)(gimme)(?=\W)/gi` or alike. The `\W` are supposed to be zero-width characters to surround my actual match.

Maybe some background. I want te replace certain words (always `\w+`) with some literal padding added, but only if it's not surrounded by a `\w`. (That does sound like a negative lookaround, but I hear JS doesn't do those!?)

(Btw: the above "gimme" is the word literal I want to replace. If that wasn't obvious.)

It has to be (?) a lookaround, because the `\W` have to be zero-width, because the intention is a `.replace(...)` and I **cannot** replace/copy the surrounding characters.

So this won't work:

```
text.replace(/(?=\W)(gimme)(?=\W)/gi, function(l, match, r) {
  return l + doMagic(match) + r;
})
```

The zero-width chars have to be ignored, so the function can return (and replace) **only**  `doMagic(match)`.

I have only very limited lookaround experience and non of it in JS. Grazie.

PS. Or maybe I need a lookbehind and those aren't supported in JS..? I'm confused?

PS. A little bit of context: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/kMs2N/show/ (ooh a link!)

Comment: lookbehind is not supported in JS - you can use word boundary shortcut though `\b`

Comment: Joanna, I love you, did I tell you that? The lowercase letter `b` is now my new hero! Sweet! Perfect! And actually much simpler than two lookarounds... If you want the rep, create an answer and it's all yours!

Comment: lol :-D see a few other options in my answer below

Comment: There are no absolute one way to do things when using regular expressions. There is always another way or work around. Words like *cannot/only* somehow don't apply here.

Comment: If you're referring to my (absolute!) **cannot**, sure it applies. It's nothing to do with regex, but with IE's inability to decently repopulate a `[contenteditable]`'s `innerHTML`. (That might be the awesomest sentence I've ever typed.)

Comment: Yeah, then maybe this isin't a regex question. Next time don't tag it as regex.

Comment: How is it not a regex question? You're totally contradicting yourself now. Whatever. Thanks for your contribution. I quit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you can use word boundary shortcut `\b` to assert that it's the whole word that you are matching.
- The easiest way to achieve what you want to do is probably to match:

`/(\s+gimme)(?=\W)/gi`

and replace with `[yourReplacement]` - i.e. capture the whitespaces before 'gimme' and then include one in the replacement.

- Another way to approach this would be capturing more characters before and after the `gimme` literal and then using the groups with backreference:

`(\W+?)gimme(\W+?)` - your match - note that this time the before and after characters are in the capturing groups 1 and 2

And you'd want to use `\1[yourReplacement]\2` as replacement string - not sure how you use backreference in JS, but the idea is to tell the engine that with `\1` you mean whatever was matched by the first captuing parenthesis. In some languages these are accessed with `$1`.

Comment: I can't capture (and replace) the surrounding characters. `innerHTML` will mess it up if I replace more than the exact match.

Comment: @Rudie - Your not replacing surrounding characters, your replacing just 'gimme'. So what do you mean it would mess it up?

Comment: If I match `\sgimme`, I have to replace the `\s` with a `\s` (or `$0` or `\0`). (The `\s` might not even be a `\s` btw. All I know is it's not a `\w`.) My "So this doesn't work"-example should be clear...

Comment: My subject/word needs a capture too btw, so the regex would be `(not)(yes+)(not)` which means I'd have to replace the `(not)`s as well. IE's `innerHTML` doesn't like that. It's all good though. Your `\b` saved my shiny metal `\s`.

Comment: @Rudie - Ok, I'll bite. How are the results of `text.replace(/([\S\s]*gimme[\S\s]*)/,"$1")` and `text.replace(/(gimme)/,"$1")`  different?

Comment: Who's talking about `\S\s`? Why throw two random regexes in the mix? They might be the same, but they're completely irrelevant. As you can see, I've found my perfect answer, so I'm done discussing this question.

Comment: @Rudy - Actually, they're not irrelevant. It makes the point that any matched text can be replaced with itself without any side affects whatsover. This is a very good thing to know.

Answer (score 2):

What you currently have will not work, for the following reason, `(?=\W)` means "the next character is not a word character", and the next thing you try to match is a literal `g`, so you have a contradiction ("next character is a `g`, but isn't a letter").

You do in fact need a lookbehind, but they are not supported by JavaScript.

Check out this article on [Mimicking Lookbehind in JavaScript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) for a possible approach.

Comment: That is correct, you need a lookbehind before and a lookahead after, I would probably use `(?<!\w)(gimme)(?!\w)`, but the negative lookbehind won't work in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a lexer/parser combo?

[This one](http://jscc.jmksf.com/) is javascript based, and comes with a spiffy [demonstration](http://jscc.jmksf.com/jscc/jscc.html).

Comment: That's a tiny bit of overkill IMO, but +1 for "spiffy" and the link.